# What is the definition of a strictly negative definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, definition

I know the definition of semi-positive, positive, semi-negative, and negative definite, but what is the definition of a strictly negative definite matrix?

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine that "strictly negative definite" means anything other than negative definite. It's just a clarification to make it absolutely clear that it is not semi-definite.

Comment: Oh, that would make sense.